# Max no of controllers in a thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I have 68 include controllers under a thread group but when I run the test, only 10 of them get executed. Is there a limit on the no of controllers that we can add under a thread group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No limit , error is somewhere else.

Note that 68 include controllers looks a bit too much, is there a reason for this ?

Comment: Actually, I have to make calls to 68 APIs as part of my test scenario. I have created separate scripts for each API call, so that they can be reused in other scenarios and I'm calling these scripts using include controllers in the main scenario script. Any suggections to implement this in a better way?